# Sheet 1 Highlighted cell will be linked with color in Sheet 2

Tags: worksheet-function

Sheet 1 Highlighted cell will be linked with color in Sheet 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bvXf.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I "think" I know what you're asking.

"*How to match the cell color to another other cell in Excel.*"

If you change the cell color in [sheet 1] [A1] color to orange, the cell in [sheet 2] [A1] will also turn orange.

I could go into detail on how to do this, but why when someone else has already invented this rickety wheel.

Enjoy!

[How To Set Cell Color Equal To Another Cell Color In Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4832-excel-set-cell-color-equal-to-another-cell-color.html)